# Accessing a local variable outside a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting data from a PHP file, and as an example, storing a variable that uses that data. It's stored within two functions:

```
$("#image1").on("click",function(){

    $(".click").one("click",function(){

        $.getJSON("getnew.php",function(data){
        var img1 = data.img1;
```

Then I have to post it to another PHP file, which is only stored within the first function.

```
$("#image1").on("click",function(){

// above stuff is first

    $.post("update.php",
        {img1link: img1}
```

but I can't access the img1 variable since it's local within the other function.

Comment: So declare it so that it's in scope for both functions.

Comment: Just make sure you don't try to use it in the outer scope before it's been set in the inner scope

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with scope, more with Asynchronous Javascript And XML being ... well asynchronous ?

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-04/async-method-patterns/

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is remove the `var` from `var img1 = data.img1;` declaration.

If you use `var` the variable will be declared in the local scope. If u just declare the variable without a `var`, it will be declared in the global scope

Comment: Whilst this may work, polluting the global scope isn't the best idea

Answer (score -1):

It's not a good practice to use global variables in any programming language. So I will recommend you to make use of saving context before going into ajax call.
Like-

```
$("#image1").on("click",function(){

    $(".click").one("click",function(){

        $.getJSON("getnew.php",function(data){
        var img1 = data.img1;
        var self=this; // This is saving current context in self variable.
       $.post("update.php",
        {img1link: self.img1} //here you can access that variable using self.
```

Comment: `this` isn't about variable scope.